My local repo refuses to push to my github account after deleting my .git folder
I'm a newbie.
I had some issues with my local repo and decided to delete the .git folder. The issue now is that I tried reinitializing git, committing it and then pushing it but then I get this error
! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<name>/<folder>.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not
hint: have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing to
hint: the same ref. If you want to integrate the remote changes, use
hint: 'git pull' before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I'm stranded and out of options, how do I push the local repo back to its original repo on github using the main branch and merging it seamlessly. Thanks
I have tried browsing and cross checking all details but I can't still find my way around. Please I need help, I'm stuck.
Thanks.

Have you made changes to your local repo that you need to check in? If not, you can just delete your local version and re-clone from GitHub.
If you do have changes you need to preserve:

Clone a new copy of your repo to another location.
Copy any changed or new files to the newly cloned copy.
Commit and push. Now your new copy is up to date.
Delete the original.

When you delete the .git folder, you're basically saying "this is not a repo any more". When you re-initialize it, you're saying "this is a different repo". In terms of commits and hashes and stuff, they are two different histories.
If you DON'T need to preserve the history, you can delete the one from GitHub and push the new one instead.
